# Take specific action depending on "foreign" subtype, without switch, casts and so on. Can we use polymorphism somehow?

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns

I faced similar problem many times, and yet haven't found good solution. What follows is a concrete example with which I'm struggling now, but the problem is actually general.

Let's say we have some application that listens for binary data from serial port, decodes it, and sends some data back if needed. This is the core functionality, and it is done by a kind of "core" module.

This core module emits events. There is an abstract type `Event`, which contains some common data such as event time, and there are some subclasses of `Event`: for example, there is an event `EventRawData` that is emitted when any raw data is received, and `EventMessage`, that is emitted when message is decoded or sent.

There is GUI which listens for these events, and takes some actions when event happens. Of course, exact action depends on exact event type. The problem is how to take special action depending on event type. `Event` itself is completely unaware of any kind of GUI (and it shouldn't be aware), so, I can't add some virtual method to `Event` that displays this event somehow.

The naive approach is to use some kind of `switch`: in C++ we would use `dynamic_cast`, in Java it would be `instanceof`, etc. This is what I've done before, and I don't like it:

```
if (my_event instanceof EventRawData){
   // ...
} else if (my_event instanceof EventMessage){
   // ...
}
```

What I can think of instead, is:

Maybe we can invent some interface for GUI, and each particular GUI should implement this interface. Then, each event could have `show()` method:

```
abstract class Event {
   // ...
   abstract void show(GuiAbstract gui);
   // ...
}
```

and when this method is invoked by some particular GUI, the GUI should pass `this` there. This is probably what is called a "dependency injection" these days.

Well, I don't like this either: I want `Event` to be completely unaware of GUI.

Or, maybe it's better to get rid of base class `Event`, make each event completely separate class, and listen for them separately. I don't like it as well: I really want all events to have some common data (such as time of the event).

Maybe there is some design pattern that I'm unaware of? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a form of [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). You could use something like the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for this.

Comment: The fact that you want your event hierarchy itself to be independent of your GUI, does not mean that you can not have a derived class from each event type that IS aware of your GUI. (or multiple derived classes from each event type each containing functionality triggered by that even in a certain context, e.g. GUI, logging, persistence etc). By using multiple inheritance, privately deriving e.g. EventMessageGuiElement from EventMessage and GuiElement, implementing certain virtual functions of GuiElement FOR THAT SPECIFIC EVENT TYPE, the amount of code duplication would be minimal.

Comment: @TartanLlama, thank you very much; I've read about visitor patter before in Stroustrup, "The C++ Programming Language", 2013; but I forgot the concept. Now you helped me to refresh my memory, I've implemented it, and it works perfectly. Please consider writing it as answer, and I'll surely accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you decouple your UI from your domain completely, you will have to have a conditional tree on type somewhere between your domain and your UI.  One option, however, is to 'hide' the condition tree in a factory, and produce a 'view model' of the event that works polymorphically:

```
// DOMAIN LAYER

public class Event {
    // some data, completely agnostic of UI
}


// USER INTERFACE LAYER

public abstract EventViewModel {
    void show();
}

public class EventViewModelFactory {
    EventViewModel createFrom(Event event) {
        if (event instanceof EventA) {
            return EventAViewModel((EventA)event);
        }
        else if (event instanceof EventB) {
            return EventBViewModel((EventB)event);
        }
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the visitor pattern ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern ) suggested by @TartanLlama in comments is more appropriate: we don't have to use any kind of `instanceof` whatsoever.